# I have input tags where user can give email.How to validate email when it is given as tags?

Tags: php, validation, email, tags

```
 <div class="form-group row" id="add_user_email_form_group">
    <label for="add_user_email" id ="lblError" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right font-weight-bold">{{ __('Phishing PDF Report Email Address') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6 add_user_email">
            <input type="text" class="form-control tags_input" id="report_notification_emails txtEmail" value="" name="report_notification_emails" multiple onkeyup="mailValidation();" />
            <span id="lblError" style="color: red"></span>
            <sub><strong>Up to 3 total email addresses</strong></sub> 
        </div>

        @error('report_notification_emails')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
```

How to validate this tag input to check email.Input type = email not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="email" multiple />` should give the functionality to have an input for multiple emails that validates each of them to be a valid email format.

The `multiple` documentation specifies that each of the emails will need to be separated by commas: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp